# How to load/populate only visible grids in gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, adapter

I am trying to load images to grid view from web. Currently I am loading images from web in the adapter class using async. My problem is when there is less number of images it works perfectly fine but when there is huge number, it takes for ever when i want to switch to another activity, My asyn tasks keeps running.

I did a lot of research and didn't find anything that works for me. Can some one please suggest if what I am doing is right or wrong also how to get the visible cells only so that I can check in the async task and change accordingly?

Comment: use this library http://square.github.io/picasso/ it works very well.

Comment: Do you know if I could use it with Volley?

Comment: This and volley can be used in parallel without issues. (I use on the app I work for)

Comment: For my app, i dont have direct url, I am sending a xmlrequest to my webservice and on response get byte[]. How do you suggest I use picasso in that case. I am totally confused.

Comment: I would change your webservice to behave like most other image web services on the planet. Pass a URL and it will return the image.

Comment: Hmm thanks. But changing web service is not under my control.. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111803/discussion-between-chitra-and-budius).